# initialization error.. but I don't know why

Tags: android

I have to use count down timer every `fragment`. Also same timer has to be implemented several times in each of some `fragments`.

So I made Timer class as below

```
public class Timerset {
private int max;
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
private boolean isPause = false;

private TimerListener listener;

public Timerset(int maxSecond, final TimerListener timerListener){
    this.max = maxSecond;
    this.listener = timerListener;
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!isPause){
                if(listener!= null){
                    listener.setTime(max);
                }
                if(max==0){
                    timer.cancel();
                }else{
                    max--;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

public void start(){
    timer.schedule(timerTask,0,1000);
}

public void stop(){
    timer.cancel();
}

public void pause(){
    isPause = true;
}

public void resume(){
    isPause = false;
}

public interface TimerListener{
    void setTime(int sec);
}
}
```

I made the object using new with param in `onCreateView` method of fragment.
like below

Global variable. :
`Timerset` `timerset1`,`timerset2`,`timerset3`,`timerset4`;

```
timerset1 = new Timerset(45, this);
timerset2 = new Timerset(45, this);
timerset3 = new Timerset(45, this);
timerset4 = new Timerset(45, this);
```

and I call the `start()` method of `Timerset` at the point it has to starts.

```
timerset1.start();
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sinjihye.tossoneshot.TimerPackage.Timerset.setTimerListener(com.example.sinjihye.tossoneshot.TimerPackage.Timerset$TimerListener)' on a **null object reference**
>           at com.example.sinjihye.tossoneshot.ActualTestPackage.Part1QuestionFragment.onCreateView(Part1QuestionFragment.java:74)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: please provide the whole `Part1QuestionFragment`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot add the picture of fragment, I just edited.Thanks

Comment: There is no `setTimerListener()` method in your `Timerset` class, as indicated by the stack trace, nor do you show where you're calling that method. Please look into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have more question, I made it in the constructor of Timerset. is it has to be made setinterfaceListener separately??

Comment: No, not necessarily. Having it as a constructor parameter is just fine. However, the stack trace says you're calling `setTimerListener()` on a null `Timerset`. If you've changed your code recently, you're likely looking at an old stack trace, old logs.

Comment: Where did you call `setTimerListener()`?

Answer (score 0):

As in you start method:

```
public void start(){
timer.schedule(timerTask,0,1000);
}
```

timerTask is referance from your `TimerSet` class. In your `TimerSet` class constructor, you initialize `TimerTask` as Local variable. change it to Instance variable of your `TimerSet` class. like this:

```
TimerTask timerTask;
public Timerset(int maxSecond, final TimerListener timerListener){
this.max = maxSecond;
this.listener = timerListener;
timer = new Timer();
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!isPause){
            if(listener!= null){
                listener.setTime(max);
            }
            if(max==0){
                timer.cancel();
            }else{
                max--;
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```